# Customized Demo is not loading to Magnolia CMS

Tags: magnolia

I have followed [Travel Demo - for developers](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Travel+Demo+-+for+developers) and manage to start Travel Demo. Now I am trying to customize templates (ftl) on magnolia-travel-tours.

I have noticed, changes to the templates are not picked up. Looks like, Since I am not specifying a version number when I am including as a dependency on my web app, Fresh copy of the  Demo is downloading when I am building the Magnolia Web App. 
This is how I put the dependency,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.esharps.projects</groupId>
        <artifactId>coreCMSProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>coreCMSProject-webapp</artifactId>
    <name>coreCMSProject: webapp</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
            <artifactId>magnolia-empty-webapp</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
            <artifactId>magnolia-empty-webapp</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.magnolia.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>magnolia-travel-tours</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Now what I have done is, I gave a version number and group ID for the magnolia-travel-tours and rebuild the magnolia-travel-tours (Had to specify the version number for magnolia-travel-demo module) and included that particular version on my webapp

pom.xml of magnolia-travel-tours

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>info.magnolia.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>magnolia-travel-demo-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../magnolia-travel-demo-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  **<groupId>info.magnolia.demo</groupId>**
  <artifactId>magnolia-travel-tours</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  **<version>0.11-CUSTOM</version>**
  <name>Magnolia Travel Tours Module</name>
  <description>Magnolia module showcasing a travel-tours website</description>

  <properties>
    <cloverCoverageThreshold>37</cloverCoverageThreshold>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Dependencies to travel-demo -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia.demo</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-travel-demo</artifactId>
      <version>**0.11-SNAPSHOT**</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now problem is, I am getting following error when I try to start the web app.

```
2016-04-22 02:33:54,906 ERROR info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener : Oops, Magnolia could not be started
info.magnolia.module.model.reader.ModuleDependencyException: The following exceptions were found while checking Magnolia modules dependencies (i.e. those in META-INF/magnolia/my-module.xml):
Module Magnolia Travel Tours Module (version 0.11.0-CUSTOM) is dependent on travel-demo (version 0.11-CUSTOM), but Magnolia Travel Demo Module (version 0.10.0) is currently installed.
Module Magnolia Travel Tours Module (version 0.11.0-CUSTOM) is dependent on mtk (version 0.10/*), but Magnolia Templating Kit (version 0.9.0) is currently installed.
info.magnolia.module.model.reader.ModuleDependencyException: The following exceptions were found while checking Magnolia modules dependencies (i.e. those in META-INF/magnolia/my-module.xml):
```

How should I customize the travel demo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to customize travel-demo without changing the dependency in the web-app that you are deploying. I assume that you have IDE that you are working with. Then I would checkout the webapp that I would like to deploy and then in its pom, I would change the travel-demo dependency which would point to my custom travel-demo. Your mistake here is that you import the empty-webapp but its already built at that time so your changes are not picked up at that time.

Please have a look at

```
      <!-- 1. Import dependency management from one of our parent poms (bundles or packs) -->
      <dependency>
        <!-- CE bundle -->
       <groupId>info.magnolia.bundle</groupId>
       <artifactId>magnolia-bundle-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>

      <!-- 2. Own modules -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.dev</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-dev-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- 3. Version overrides for modules in this project -->
      <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>info.magnolia.contacts</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>magnolia-contacts</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>${contactsVersion}</version>-->
      <!--</dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <!-- animal-sniffer doesn't support java 1.8 yet -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Basically this dev-project is containing a web-app that you can deploy and you may change any dependency there. It is commented in depth so that it would be trivial to work with. Then in the end, you have to deploy the dev-project's war.

Cheers,

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to usderstand. By the way I dont have access to the link you have shared as well. Appriciate if you can elaborate. I have build the webapp again after adding the dependancy. Are you refereing to checkout the webapp code and build instaed of adding following as a dependancy ?

Comment: Yes, checkout the webapp code and add the dependency on that webapp code's pom file, then build the dependency.

Comment: I added the answer and added  a pom file there